# Set Html Checkbox checked from code behind without runat=server

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, checkbox

I have checkboxes in my aspx page as :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="daySelectors" value="monday"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="daySelectors" value="tuesday"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="daySelectors" value="wednesday"/>
```

I am not using CheckBoxList control as these checkboxes are at different areas in my html and i need value of only selected checkboxes.
Now, I can get the values of selected Checkboxes using

```
String dayselector = Request.Form["daySelectors"];
```

It works fine until here. The problem is how can i make the checkboxes checked from code behind i.e. my aspx.cs page. The scenario is when i come to this page i have the checkboxes values that need to be checked by default. How can i do this using the values. 
One way that comes to mind is i can trigger a jquery/ Javascript function from .cs passing in the values. In that case how can i set checkbox checked using their values from jquery.

Comment: If you want everything from `.cs` why jQuery/javascript tags?

Comment: It seems you are working against ASP.NET rather than using it to solve your issue? Why no runat="server"? If you decided these should be client side only, then you would need to use jQuery or something from the client side to bind and update.

Comment: I have the values in .cs but i can trigger a jquery/ Javascript function from .cs passing in the values. In that case how can i set checkbox checked using their values

Comment: @Marius I just want to avoid the if(checkbox.checked){ then pick value} for all checkboxes

Comment: You can still access the Request.Form[] values, or get the values via the server side control (checkbox.checked).

Comment: @MariusGeorge When i set runat=server for checkboxes i get null in `String dayselector = Request.Form["daySelectors"];
`

Comment: @isumit, naming containers can change the name of your control. Inspect the name in your browser dev tools first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i just called a Javascript method from my .cs file using

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, typeof(string), "uniqueKey","SetCheckBox('sunday');",true)
```

and to the JavaScript method passed in the value of CheckBox that needs to be checked :

```
function SetCheckBox(value) {
        $("input:checkbox[value=" + value + "]").attr("checked", true);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot. If the control is not `runat=server`, you don't have access to it in code behind.

Comment: @isumit, you may want to know [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), otherwise the question will remain unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely don't want runat="server" (but I think your reason for not wanting to use it might be based on a misconception), you can always have some custom properties in your Page class and then pump attributes (like "selected") straight into your checkbox markup...

```
 <input type="checkbox" selected="<%=SelectedAttribute%>" .... />
```

Answer (score 0):

In the checkbox tag:

in the codebehind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (IsPostBack)
        {
            try
            {
                if (Request.Form["Archived"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    Session["checkboxstate"] = " checked='checked' ";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception eee)
            {
                Session["checkboxstate"] = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Worked for me.